# Deleting form fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to add and delete a form field with jQuery 1.9. It's adding a field just fine but when trying to delete it nothing is happening.

Here's the HTML...

```
<div class="control-group spacing-top">
<label for="answer[]" class="control-label required">Answers</label>
<div id="answers" class="controls">
    <div class="answer-holder input-append">
        <input class="input-xxlarge" placeholder="Answer" name="answer[]" type="text" value="" id="answer[]">   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>

    </div>
</div>
<button class="button button-secondary answer-add"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Answer</button>
```

And here's the jQuery...

```
$(function () {
    var i = $('.answer-holder').length;
    $('.answer-add').on('click', function () {
        $('<div class="input-append"><input class="input-xxlarge" name="answer[]" type="text" value="" id="answer_' + i + '"><button class="answer-delete">Remove</button></div>').appendTo($('#answers'));
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('.answer-delete').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent('.answer-holder').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two** things to do

**First**

Add `class` `answer-holder` to the div when `creating`

**Second**

Use `$(document).on('click','.answer-delete', function () {` in place of `$('.answer-delete').on('click', function () {`

**Full code**

```
$(function () {
    var i = $('.answer-holder').length;
    $('.answer-add').on('click', function () {
        $('<div class="input-append answer-holder"><input class="input-xxlarge" name="answer[]" type="text" value="" id="answer_' + i + '"><button class="answer-delete">Remove</button></div>').appendTo($('#answers'));
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click','.answer-delete', function () {
        $(this).parent('.answer-holder').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55nqu/)

Comment: Thanks Rohan, you nailed it!!

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation, BTW, `answer-delete` element doesn't seem to have for parent `.answer-holder` element:

```
$('#answers').on('click','.answer-delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('#answers').find('.answer-holder').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `on` is wrong in this case, since `answer-delete` is an dynamic element you need to use event delegation based event handler

```
$('#answers').on('click', '.answer-delete', function () {
    $(this).parent('.answer-holder').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the `.answer-delete` selector like so:

```
$('#answers').on('click', '.answer-delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

#### [Docs: Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 0):

What others have said, you need to delegate the .on function

However, your click function is looking for a parent of `.answer-holder` - Which your script isn't adding, so you need to add that into your function that adds the input box.

See my [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dAHd7/)